# some flutter widgets not showing at first when app starts in listview page inside a tabbarview

Tags: listview, dart, widget, flutter

I made and simple voting app that has a `listview.builder` that is built by a `StreamBuilder` that gets data from the Firebase database. The problem here is that when I try on android phones with low - medium specs it does not load all the widgets of each row in the list. The widgets that only show are the card and a like button, some text views, and a `ClipOval` with a photo does not load. I had tried in ios version and android phones with android Nougat and it works fine. The problem shows up with phones under android Lollipop I think because these are slower phones. But when I switch to another tab and return to this page the list shows fine. Here is a screenshot of the list not loading:
[list not showing][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqNcF.png
And here is the code of the `StreamBuilder` which shows a message if the list is not ready (there is no internet connection or data is not ready yet):

```
    widgetLista = new StreamBuilder<Event>(
      stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(BaseDeDatos.miRef).onValue,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> event){
        //sino tiene datos entonces cargar la última foto de los resultados
        if(!event.hasData){ 

          if(Utilidades.LISTA_RESULTADOS_OFFLINE != null){  
          return _cargarListaOffLine( lista: Utilidades.LISTA_RESULTADOS_OFFLINE); 
          }else{
            return new Center(child: new Text('Cargando Lista...'));
          }
          
        }else{
          //si hay internet y se descarga el dato entonces mostrar lista de internet

          LinkedHashMap<dynamic,dynamic> map = event.data.snapshot.value;
          
          List tempList = [];//lista para usar en getfila en el listview

          ObjetoEncodearCandidato encodearCandidato = new ObjetoEncodearCandidato();//para guardar última foto    
     
          
          map.forEach((dynamic n,dynamic v){
            LinkedHashMap mapVotos = v ;
            tempList.add(new Voto(candidato: n as String,votos: mapVotos['votos']));             
            encodearCandidato.agregarCandidato( nombreCandidato: n, votosCandidato: mapVotos['votos'] );
          });

          //guardar ultima foto, aqui se transforma a json string y se almacena
          var db = new BaseDeDatosHelper();

          //se consulta si ya existe una foto para saber si se inserta o actualiza
          db.leerSiTablaTieneRegistrosFotoVotos(1).then((tieneFoto){

            if(tieneFoto == true){
              db.actualizarFotoVotos( fotoJson:  encodearCandidato.obtenerObjetoEnJson() )
              .then((resultado) => print("se ha actualizado la foto: $resultado"));
            }else{
              db.crearRegistroFotoVotos(new RegistroVotoJson( foto: encodearCandidato.obtenerObjetoEnJson()));
            }
          });
          

          listaStreamCandidatos = tempList;              

          _totalVotos = _calcularVotosTotales(tempList);

          //TODO:Falta Ordenar el tempList para que se muestren los candidatos de mayor a menor
          _ordenarSegunVotos(tempList);  

          Utilidades.LISTA_RESULTADOS_OFFLINE = tempList;//guarda esta lista en caso de que no haya internet            

           return new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: (tempList == null ? 0 : tempList.length),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int pos){
              //recibe el voto correspondiente a la posición
              return _getFila(tempList[pos], pos, _totalVotos);
            },
          );
        }//fin else             
      }
    );
```

In this code, the `StreamBuilder` create the list if there is data and saves it SQfLite database for further when the user does not have an internet connection. This list data also is saved in an instance variable of my Utils class for quicker use. Let me know if you need more info about the code. I really appreciate your help.

Here is the code of the _getFila method that builds the row in the listview:

```
Widget _getFila(Voto voto, int pos, int totalVotos) {

      //obtener la posicion de imagenes de este voto en la carpeta imagenes
      int indiceCandidato = Utilidades.listaCandidatos.indexOf(voto.candidato);
      
      String porcentajeVotos = totalVotos == 0 ? '0.0' : ((voto.votos/totalVotos) * 100).toStringAsFixed(2) ;

      String sufijoVotos = voto.votos == 1 ? 'voto' : 'votos';

      return new Card(
        child: new Row(

          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: new ClipOval(                                                                         
                child: new Image.asset("images/${Utilidades.LISTA_NOMBRE_IMAGENES[indiceCandidato]}.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,width: _ancho * 0.12,height: _ancho * 0.12, ),//el % del ancho de la pantalla que tendrá la imagen del candidato
                
              )
              ),
            new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text("${voto.candidato}" , style: new TextStyle(fontSize: _ancho * 0.04),),
                //new FittedBox(child:new Text("${voto.candidato}" , ) ,),
                new Row(                      
                  children: <Widget>[
                 new Text("$porcentajeVotos%", style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: _ancho * 0.046),), 
                  new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),),
                 new Text(": ${voto.votos} $sufijoVotos", style: new TextStyle( color:Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: _ancho * 0.0365))
                ],), 
                new SizedBox(
                  width: _ancho * 0.6,//el % del ancho de la pantalla que tendrá la barra de progreso                    
                  child: new LinearProgressIndicator(value: (voto.votos/totalVotos), backgroundColor: Colors.white,),//Calcula el porcentaje de votos del candidato
                ), 
              ],
            ),
            
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new GestureDetector(
                    //este icono se actualiza cuando se modifcan los votos debido a que se vuelve a pintar la lista con el streambuilder
                    child: new Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: (miVotoActual != null && miVotoActual == voto.candidato ? Colors.blue : Colors.black )),
                    onTap:(){                           
                      _insertarRegistro(nombreCandidato: "${(listaStreamCandidatos[pos] as Voto).candidato}");
                      
                      },
                  ),                      
                  new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0))
                  ]
              ) ,
            ),
           
          ],
        ) ,
      ); 
  }
```

Comment: **save it sqflite database for further when the user does not have internet connection**, Since you are using Firebase you dont have to worry about internet connection for both fetch and push

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I save the last result that was obtained with firebase, so the user can see the list without internet connection with at least this outdated result. ¿Could be this process the reason why these phones cannot load all this widgets?

Comment: Firebase works offline, everything is synced even if you add something to the firebase from your app when there is no internet connection, data will push whenever you connect to the internet. This cannot be the problem for your situation and im sorry I cannot understand most of the code

Comment: I added the code for the _getFila method that builds the row of the listview.¿Could this combination of widgets be the problem?